# ember.js: prepare code to move from ember 1.x to ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js

**My question is: Can someone direct me in moving from controller based application to component base application?**

I am building a map application for my dog training club. We are specialized in helping finding missing people.
In order to organize our training, we need an application to draw trails and add items on them etc.

I've started an app using Ember-Cli and OpenLayers-3. The application is working nicely, but I would like to move the code from controller based to component base approach.

I would like also to use more routing as at the moment, I have only one route and all user interactions are handled using actions.

I've setup a repository on github for those who would be kind enough to help me:

https://github.com/mylen/mantrailling

if you want to checkout the code and test the app localy, you'll need to modify the referer using a header mod in your navigator to use http://demo.melard.fr

You can see a beta of the website at that page :

http://recherche.utilitaire.melard.fr/beta/map

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is: Can someone direct me in moving from controller based application to component base application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we should clarify the intended uses of components, controllers and routes in ember.js.

**Components** are similar to Views, but they are isolated and therefore used to create reusable pieces of code, that handle the visual representation of your models.

**Controllers** are mainly used to decorate your models, but also to hold application state.

**Routes** represent you current application state. They are responsible for loading your models and to initialize your controllers.

To solve your first problem (controllers -> components), you only need to move all view related stuff, and only this, into components. Your code that decorate your model, for example the active flag of a way-point, remains in the controller. You only need to bind the data of your models/controllers to the components, via embers data binding. (http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/components/passing-properties-to-a-component)

Your second problem (use routes) is a bit harder to solve, I think. First you need to find all of the states your app currently have. After that, you should move your model loading and saving stuff into this routes.

**Edit**
Some references describing the problem.

https://github.com/ef4/rfcs/blob/routeable-components/active/0000-routeable-components.md

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgycDZjOnIg

**Edit 2**
Your question is highly related to `How to move ember from 1.x to 2.0`, because the changes you mentioned will come along with ember 2.0.

Here are some additional links that describe how to prepare best for this upgrade.

https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97

https://speakerdeck.com/tomdale/ember-2-dot-0-in-practice

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-a-good-way-to-do-this-in-ember-2-0-no-itemcontroller-no-arraycontroller/6649

You can find a lot of resources if you search for `ember 2.0`.

**Edit 3**
Here is I think the most informative source for keeping up with new Ember releases:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsydQzQF4Ww

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I started other from scratch using a more object oriented design. I am using model / services / components. I use the services in order to deal with non-UI matters, and the components for UI logic. I've been told that ember would completely move from controller oriented patterns to components oriented. I am really struggling to understand the use of router in Ember. Usually, I used routers in my application to direct the user to the requested page, but in a single page application, I do not understand how to use them...

Comment: Could you please direct me to some documentation (not the ember.js guide, iut doesn't explain a lot)

Comment: Do you have some references for `...ember would completely move from controller ... to components`, I have never heard about that. The only thing I have seen is, that ember moves from views to components and that most people misuse controllers instead of using routes?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, I'll edit my question in according to your answer. Might help someone else.