# Ember Controller vs Ember ArrayController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I don't get a clear difference as to when to use `Ember.Controller` and when to use `Ember.ArrayController` and its usage.

Comment: `ArrayController` will become deprecated (https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97), use `Ember.Controller` instead. Ember will also move from controllers to components on 2.0 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861006/ember-js-prepare-code-to-move-from-ember-1-x-to-ember-2-0)

Comment: thank you cory and kured

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a Controller, you could do `{{#each item in model}}` in your template.

With ArrayController, you could simply do `{{#each item}}`.

Could. ArrayController is deprecated because it was obscuring the logic, you should never use it. The Controller is also being deprecated in favor of routeable components, somewhere in Ember 2.1 or 2.2.

Current strategy is the following:

- Forget ArrayController, ObjectController and View.
- Use components for everything.
- Until Ember 2.1/2.2, you're unable to use a component for a root template of any route. For that template, you'll have to use a controller.
- Don't put any logic into that controller. Simply place a component in its template and pass the model through. Use such controllers only for query params and other stuff that components are incapable of (yet).
- In routes, don't use `setupController`. Instead, put everything into a model, turning it into a hash of models. `RSVP.hash` is your friend.
- When routable components are available, replace controllers with components.

PS The syntax for `each` is changing to `{{#each model as |item|}}`.

Comment: @Andrey, not enough reps; am poor

Comment: Set the tick mark next to helpful answers of all your questions.